# How do I display my calculator result with a thousands separator?

Tags: ios, swift, calculator

I am very new to Swift. I am making a simple calculator. But the thing is that I cannot create a thousands separator. In the code below, when entering the number in `TextField1`, I want to enter it automatically with a thousands separator. For example, when writing, it should be written as 100.000 instead of 100000.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var myTextField3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var myTextField2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var myTextField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var myLabel1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var myLabel2: UILabel!
    
    @IBAction func myButton1(_ sender: Any) {
        myLabel1.isHidden = false
        myLabel2.isHidden = false
        let anapara = Float(myTextField1.text!)
        let vade = Float(myTextField2.text!)
        let ay = Float(myTextField3.text!)
        
        let outputValue = Int(((anapara! / 100 * vade! * ay!) + anapara!) / ay!)
        let outputValue2 = Int((anapara! / 100 * vade! * ay!) + anapara!)

        let formattedOutputValue = outputValue.withSeparator
        let formattedOutputValue2 = outputValue2.withSeparator

        myLabel1.text = "Aylık \(formattedOutputValue) TL"
        myLabel2.text = "Toplam Ödeme \(formattedOutputValue2) TL"
    }
}

extension Numeric {
    var withSeparator: String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.groupingSeparator = "."
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted appears like it should be doing what you want. What actually happens when you run this code?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if there is a best approach.

What you can try to do is:

1. Listen all the text change with `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool`
2. Split the text on the decimal and integer
3. format the integer number with `NumberFormatter`
4. concatenate booth number and update on textfield

this code can have a lot of improves but does the work if I understood the problem right

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    let decimalSeparator = ","
    let groupingSeparator = "."

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldExample: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.groupingSeparator = groupingSeparator
        formatter.decimalSeparator = decimalSeparator
        formatter.groupingSize = 3
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        guard let text = textField.text,
           let textRange = Range(range, in: text) else {
            return true
        }

        let updatedText = text.replacingCharacters(in: textRange,
                                                   with: string)

        let numberSplitted = updatedText.components(separatedBy: decimalSeparator)
        guard numberSplitted.first != nil,
              let onlyDigits = numberSplitted.first?.digits,
              let number = Int(onlyDigits) else {
            return true
        }
        var decimalNumber = ""
        let intergerNumber = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number)) ?? "0"

        if numberSplitted.count > 1, let decimalValue = numberSplitted.last {
            decimalNumber = ",\(decimalValue.digits)"
        }

        textField.text = String("\(intergerNumber)\(decimalNumber)")

        return false
    }
}

extension String {
    var digits: String {
        return components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
            .joined()
    }
}
```

Comment: I did using @IBOutlet because looks like you are developing using storyboard